# Bluetooth LE and ANCS in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, apple-push-notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can I develop a service on iOS to register with ANCS so that when iPhone gets a notification the service go through my device BT LE protocol to notify the band?
And I read at http://blog.punchthrough.com/post/63658238857/the-apple-notification-center-service-or-wtf-is. I see "ANCS is managed automatically by the iOS device, or “Notification Provider” as its known in ANCS parlance. What this means for you as a developer is that you won’t need to write code to manage ANCS on the iOS side." It means i don't need write code in iOS side that have to implement in my device  BT LE ? Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. As the link mentions, you use "service solicitation" to get the iOS device's attention while it is passively scanning. 
You don't need to have an app running on the iOS device, you don't need to submit anything to the App Store--you don't even need to pay to become a developer.
Also, I should mention, your hardware design does not need to be submitted to the Apple MFi program.

Comment: Thanks, So if my BT LE device implement ANSC, when mobile app connected to BTLE device, mobile app auto push these notifications to BTLE device, is it right?

Comment: Correct. Built-in or 3rd party apps send notification up to iOS--iOS checks to see notifications for that app are enabled--iOS pushes notification to subscribed external hardware via ANCS. I've only verified with iMessage but should work will all mobile apps.

Comment: More things,when there is an SMS coming in, will ANCS send signal to our BLE device (peered)? What will be sent by ANCS to BLE device?
And If it is WeChat app, how and what will be sent to our BLE device, if WeChat has an incoming message...? Thanks much

Comment: Check tha ANCS spec Appendix for the information sent over BLE. I have not verified SMS-only iMessage--which for iOS are sort of the same. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Specification/Specification.html

Comment: I read the specs, when ios device paired with BLE device supported ANCS, iOS device will send command to push notifications?